# Python-crontab job.write() causing a fileIO error

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to use python-crontab to run a job, but when I try to save the job with `cron.write()`, I get a fileIO error `IOError("Please specify user or filename to write.")
OSError: Please specify user or filename to write.` Below is my full code:

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab()
job  = cron.new(command='python3 /backend/main/update.py')
job.minute.every(1)
cron.write()
```

Comment: What’s the issue? That error message is quite clear, no? Even if it isn’t, there are only 4 lines of code to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a username to the CronTab initializer to enable write.

Something like this

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user='your username')
job = cron.new(command='python helloworld.py')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```